# Musixmatch api not returning the "album_coverart_100x100" field

Tags: api, musixmatch

When I use the `album.get` method, it returns the full album data, but does not have the `album_coverart_100x100` field, nor does it have any field containing the cover art.

this is the response I have received after fetching the "Just the way you are" album

````
"message": {
"header": {
"status_code": 200,
"execute_time": 0.013628005981445
},
"body": {
"album": {
"album_id": 17501798,
"album_mbid": "",
"album_name": "Just The Way You Are (Bruno Mars Tribute Mixes)",
"album_rating": 7,
"album_release_date": "2010-07-27",
"artist_id": 26672558,
"artist_name": "#1 Bruno Mars Tribute Band",
"primary_genres": {
"music_genre_list": [
{
"music_genre": {
"music_genre_id": 14,
"music_genre_parent_id": 34,
"music_genre_name": "Pop",
"music_genre_name_extended": "Pop",
"music_genre_vanity": "Pop"
}
}
]
},
"album_pline": "2010 Campbell Trax",
"album_copyright": "2010 Campbell Trax",
"album_label": "Campbell Trax",
"restricted": 0,
"updated_time": "2014-02-23T14:29:14Z",
"external_ids": {
"spotify": [],
"itunes": [
"384698043"
],
"amazon_music": []
}
}
}
}
}```
````

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Struggling with the same issue.

Comment: @GD1 I started using the spotify api instead